# multiline chart in d3 with long format data

Tags: d3.js

I would like to make a multi line chart in d3. Most examples I've seen use wide format data. My data is more complex than wide format will allow, it has multiple grouping structures. Each subject is scored on multiple days and is in a treatment group. Here's an example:

```
Subject Score Time Group
Sub1    19.0  1    1
Sub1    19.0  2    1
Sub2    18.9  1    1
Sub2    19.1  2    1
Sub3    20.7  1    2
Sub3    19.5  2    2
```

I would like to make different lines for each **Subject**, but colored by **Group**. I tried putting this into JSON format, which looks like this:

```
[{"Subject" : "Sub1", "Score":"19.0", "Time":"1", "Group" : "1"} ...]
```

I imagine that I could convert the data to wide, add each svg path individually and than individually select each svg and than change the color, but I wondered if there was a way to work with this data structure without having to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't need to change the structure of the data at all. You can use [`d3.nest()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_nest) to restructure your data in d3 as needed. The code would look something like (modulo scales)

```
var nested = d3.nest()
               .key(function(d) { return d.Subject; })
               .entries(data);
var line = d3.svg.line()
             .x(function(d) { return d.Time; })
             .y(function(d) { return d.Score; });
svg.selectAll("path").data(nested).enter()
   .append("path")
   .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.values[0].Group); })
   .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });
```